# iMac (Mid) 2010 - Slow WiFi

Tags: networking, drivers, mac

New member here. I have been running Ubuntu on an old Mid 2010 iMac and it does it's job. Mainly run a plex server on it. When i set it up i had to install drivers for the networking to work and it seemed to be fine. I didn't notice any lack of performance from the wifi as the only internet we had in the house was 4G.

Yesterday I had fibre installed and my new macbook is getting around 700Mbs download and 600Mbs upload. However the iMac running ubutu which is sat right next to it is only getting around 53Mb/s download and 49Mb/s upload.

Does anyone know why or what I can do to unlock the full force of the fibre? I found some other posts while searching online that it could be the wrong driver and tried to follow a few guides but no luck as of yet.

Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.13.0-44-generic x86_64)

Results of: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR928X Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002a] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Apple Inc. AirPort Extreme [106b:008f]
        Kernel driver in use: ath9k
        Kernel modules: ath9k
```

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I have added the OS details. Does this help?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I have edited the question to provide this.

Comment: It depends on your AP (router) too. But you won't get very high speeds with this old 2.4 GHz Wi-Fi adapter. The question is not related to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Quite often, a new technology, as in your case, fiber, requires a new modem-router device. Typically, these are set up in advance by the provider with default settings that strive to fit all possible situations and users.

Many hardware-driver-firmware combinations in Linux and, I suspect, specifically, Network Manager, struggle to stay connected when the channel or the encryption method or even the frequency are ever changing. Therefore, I recommend several steps to help make your connection more stable and faster.

Please check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I recommend a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred.

Your wireless may be dropping because there are two wireless access points with the same name and password. This is typical when you have a 2.4 gHz segment and a 5 gHz segment of the same router. Your wireless may be roaming, looking for a better connection. If this is the case, I suggest that you rename the access points; something like myrouter2.4 and myrouter5.

I recommnd connection to the faster 5 gHz segment only as it is much faster.

After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and close (Ctrl+x followed by Enter) the text editor.

Comment: Thanks, I'm away for 10 days now, will have to test this when I get back. Sorry